# Where does the convention of using /healthz for application health checks come from?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

In the Kubernetes/Docker ecosystem there is a convention of using `/healthz` as a health-check endpoint for applications.

Where does the name 'healthz' come from, and are there any particular semantics associated with that name?

Answer (score 415, accepted):

It historically comes from Google’s internal practices. They're called "z-pages".

The reason it ends with `z` is to reduce collisions with actual application endpoints with the same name (like `/status`). See this talk for more: https://vimeo.com/173610242

Similar endpoints (at least inside Google) are `/varz`, `/statusz`, `/rpcz`. Services developed at Google automatically get these endpoints to export their health and metrics and there are tools that collect the exposed metrics/statuses from all the deployed services.

Open source tools like Prometheus implement this pattern (since original authors of Prometheus are also ex-Googlers) by coming to a well-known endpoint to collect metrics from your application. Similarly [OpenCensus](http://opencensus.io) allows you to expose z-pages from your app (ideally on a different port) to diagnose problems.

Comment: Go expvar https://golang.org/pkg/expvar/ is quite close to /varz

Comment: @AhmeB: Thank you for the video link. it help me understand little more about healthz

Comment: Question is answered at 26:55 in the talk (but this answer already contains pretty much the entire answer given by Kelsey).

Comment: Ask about the employee who used the handle @statusz