# /healthz route of an app deployed on Google App Engine returns 404

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible, streamlit

HTTP requests for a `/healthz` route on an app deployed on Google App Engine don't seem to reach the `/healthz` endpoint within the app. 
Instead, a `404` page is served, apparently from the GCP infrastructure. 
Can I know how to override this behaviour and make these requests reach my app?

Thank you.

[image].

A bit more background:

I'm deploying a [Streamlit](https://www.streamlit.io/) app on Google App Engine.
Streamlit web UI appear to be sending requests to the `/healthz` endpoint periodically, and when these requests fail, Streamlit app stops working and displays an error message as below.

[image]

Comment: The latest release of Streamlit fixes this /healthz endpoint clash with GCP. Please see v1.18 in the change logs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some URL paths ending in `z`, including `/healthz`, are reserved for use by App Engine and cannot be used.

Comment: There's more information about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380939/where-does-the-convention-of-using-healthz-for-application-health-checks-come-f).

Comment: Fix for /healthz conflict with GCP in streamlit v1.18

Answer (score 6):

I have managed to get around the healthz conflict in a rather nasty way. I also enabled `session_affinity` to help with websocket connections.

here is my `app.yaml`, ill explain the healthz fix below:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
# This is a horrible workaround to get streamlit working on app engine
# https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/has-anyone-deployed-to-google-cloud-platform/931/20
entrypoint: find ${VIRTUAL_ENV}/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit -type f \( -iname \*.py -o -iname \*.js \) -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/healthz/health-check/g' && streamlit run sim_v3.py --server.port $PORT --server.enableCORS=false

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

network:
  session_affinity: true
```

The hack is happening in the entrypoint command. I am finding all files in the python virtualenv dependencies folder, `site-packages`, that are either `.py` or `.js` and replacing `healthz` with `health-check`

If you are intending on supporting a deployed streamlit app, I suggest you avoid this solution. It will break if

- the version of python changes in the google python runtime
- streamlit make a change that would break this inline replacement
- google decide to change their folder naming conventions

Comment: Great hack here - streamlit package has released a stable fix for this /healthz issue in v1.18

Answer (score 1):

The latest release of Streamlit fixes this /healthz endpoint clash with GCP.  Please see v1.18 in the [change logs](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/changelog).

Please upgrade to the latest Streamlit version.