# healthz endpoint on GAE returns 404

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am running an NodeJS application on GAE and trying to have a healthz endpoint to return the service status.
I am facing issue where it returns 404 for `/healthz` endpoint while it works if I were using `/health`. Is there anyway to use `/healthz` instead?

I have heard about that Cloud Run uses `/healthz` as a reserved endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

> I have heard about that Cloud Run uses `/healthz` as a reserved endpoint.

You heard it right, it is mentioned in the [github](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/3028#issuecomment-1062030320) and [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#ah) that it is not possible to use paths ending with `z`. Since ,`/healthz` is reserved for `cloud run`. Please note that as mentioned by @Dustin Ingram at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64245718/17477508) `/healthz` is also reserved by the `app engine` to check the health of your application. Hence, you are facing an issue with `/healthz` endpoint while it works fine if you were using `/health` endpoint.